# ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\project\projekt'

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I have been looking at different answers but its not working for me, when I try to run `npm run start:dev` on windows, I got this error:

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\project\projekt'

My `package.json` file is:

```
{
  "name": "projekt",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-loader": "^15.8.3",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-turbolinks": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
  }
}
```

My `webpack.config.js` file is:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/',
    filename: 'specs.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'buble-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()]
};
```